# What is CCSID='...' on a connection string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on moving an old asp code to .net.

on the `strCon` (the connection to the database) one of the parameter is:

```
strCon=".....;CCSID=1255;"
```

I'm not sure what that means, I researched online but didn't find anything.

Can anybody explains what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCSID), CCSID means "Coded Character Set Identifier". Which sounds a little like "code page" and Windows has a [codepage 1255 for Hebrew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195057.aspx). If your application deals with text data that's in Hebrew, this may be the reason for it (but read the next paragraph!).

It may be legacy cruft left over from an old database or driver which handled different encodings via the connection string - it's not a standard parameter in SQL Server connection strings. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx

Try removing that portion of the connection string; it *may* not be needed. The only way to be sure is to test.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I never saw it before but your explanation makes much of sence, thank you!